# Apache cannot access files

Tags: django, raspberry-pi, apache2, pi

Im trying to set up an apache-server for a django-developed website on a raspbery Pi.

```
sudo chown 777 /media/pi/website/
```

When I'm trying to give the server permissions to access the files (wsgi, css, js, html ++), the console returns that I dont have premission. I'm trying as root@pi and sudo, and nothing works. It just gives back: "Operation not allowed".

Answer (score 1):

How about your SELinux config?

My guess your host is enforcing SELinux and your directory does not have the right security context.

This is mine:

```
cat /etc/selinux/config 
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
# enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
# permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
# disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
SELINUX=permissive
# SELINUXTYPE= can take one of these two values:
# default - equivalent to the old strict and targeted policies
# mls     - Multi-Level Security (for military and educational use)
# src     - Custom policy built from source
SELINUXTYPE=default

# SETLOCALDEFS= Check local definition changes
SETLOCALDEFS=0
```

Comment: Thank you :D I have the same problem with "chown"...